# The heuristic explanation of Copula.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability

Suppose $f(x, y)$ is a two-variable probability density function. Let $f_x(x)$ be a peripheral density function defined by $f_x(x) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y) \, dy$. In the similar vein, we have $f_y(y) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y) \, dx$. The copula is defined as follows$\colon$

$$
C(u, v) := f\left(f_x^{-1}(u), f_y^{-1}(v)\right).
$$

Q. What is a *heuristic* explanation of $C(u, v)$ with respect to the probability theory in view of the original $f(x, y)$? How is $C(u, v)$ related to $f(x, y)$ from the probability reasoning?

I would like to know very simple conceptual explanation, or a simple example.

Comment: Are you sure that you intend to invert the "density function"? I think it should be the cumulative distribution function (cdf).

Comment: I also think that $C$ should be defined by $C(u,v)=F(F^{-1}_x(u),F^{-1}_y(v))$, where $F_\cdot$ is the cdf and $F^{-1}$ is supposed to be the generalized inverse.

Comment: The whole Idea behind this relies actually on the inverse transform method. I.e. If $U$ is unifromly distributed on $[0,1]$ and $F$ some cdf of a distribution $\mathcal{D}$ then $F^{-1}(U)$ has also distribution $\mathcal{D}$. If you would have say a realization $(u_1,v_1),\ldots,(u_n,v_n)$ of a random vector $(U,V)$ with joint density as you described, then $C(u_i,v_i)$ $(i=1,\ldots,n)$ would be a realization of a jointly unifromly distributed random vector. But it would mentain the dependence structure of $(U,V)$.

Comment: Now with the inverse transform method you can transform this to any other distribution i.e. normal distribution, exponential distribution ect. but with the same dependence structure as $(U,V)$.

Comment: @MackeyTopology You can post this as a reply to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The copula should be defined in this way
$C(u,v)=F(F_x^{-1}(u),F_y^{-1}(u))$

...see my comments for further clarifications.